# Add custom color to outlook calendar

Tags: microsoft-outlook, microsoft-outlook-2016

Actually it is only possible to choose between 1 of 9 colors. Is there a way to add additional colors to the outlook calendar? Or is there a hack to change the existing ones?

[image]

Comment: I know this is a somewhat older post, but I have the same question. But I noticed that when adding a colleagues' calendar, sometimes a non-default color is used. But I can't find a way to set a custom non-default color myself. If I want to change it, only the default colors are shown.

Answer (score 1):

Looks to be a fixed palette, which can't be edited from File > Options > Calendar either.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

If you mean the color of the whole calendar, I'm afraid that Outlook could only support the 9 colors for now and we could not make changes to it. If you still want more colors to be available, please try voting in [the Outlook User voice](https://outlook.uservoice.com/forums/322590-outlook-for-windows-desktop-application/suggestions/33550096-increase-the-number-of-color-options-in-the-outloo), Microsoft may notice it and add it in the later version.

Comment: Sadly, the link is dead.

Answer (score 0):

Older versions of Outlook allowed custom colours (I think 2010 or 2012), but just as desktop customisations were dumbed down for Windows 10, the same applies for more recent versions of Outlook. Perhaps this explains how Lisa's colleague above managed to use a non-standard colour.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Though, it also depends whether you mean customising the colour of the calendar or the colour of your different appointment categories - there are 25 possible colours for those